# upload doc in a folder to google doc with python language

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gdata, google-docs-api

> I want to upload document file to a folder in google docs. Any code
>   will be appreciated.

I am trying to do it

```
entry = gdata.docs.data.DocsEntry(title=atom.data.Title(text='foldername'))  content_type = gdata.docs.service.SUPPORTED_FILETYPES['PDF']  ms = gdata.MediaSource(file_path='C:\Users\user\Desktop\prova.pdf', content_type= content_type)  entry = sample.gd_client.Upload(ms, 'MyDocTitle', folder_or_uri=entry)
```

My problem is to declare the folder_or_uri where the doc have to put inseide.

Comment: Please post your code so far and be specific about the problem you are having with it. "Do the whole job for me for free" isn't what SO is for.

Comment: my problem is to define folder_or_uri=dest_folder......                                        new_spreadsheet = client.Upload('/path/to/your/test.csv', 'MyDocTitle', content_type='text/csv', folder_or_uri=dest_folder)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Google Docs API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CreatingDocumentsAndFiles).  Without code or more information it is impossible to help you any more.

Comment: I saw it...my problem is to define folder_or_uri=dest_folder......                                        new_spreadsheet = client.Upload('/path/to/your/test.csv', 'MyDocTitle', content_type='text/csv', folder_or_uri=dest_folder)